# How do I install the latest python-opencv in 64-bit Ubuntu?

Tags: 64-bit, 32-bit, opencv, python-2.7

I heard that OpenCV supports only 32 bit Python.

But my OS is Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit and it has Python 2.7 64 bit.

How can I install latest OpenCV-Python bindings on this system for 32 bit Python?

.

Answer (score 1):

You heard wrong.

Installing `python-opencv` on 12.04 64-bit works just fine. See [`apt-get` log](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/1077751/) for details.

Comment: Does it work as same as 32-bit ?

Comment: Yes, it does afaik.

Comment: but how to get opencv 2.4.2 ? it is still opencv 2.3 in ubuntu repo.

Comment: also, in cv2.line() function, it says, `lineType` is not a valid argument. But it works fine in 32 bit Python.